# Is possible to use $(this) and universal selector (*)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if it is possible to use universal selector with `$(this)`.
When, for example, I want delete all inline CSS from the element and its children I use this code:

```
$('#element, #element *').attr('style','');
```

But if i have `$(this)` what is the code?

Maybe I have to try:

```
 $(this, this+'*').attr('style','');
```

Comment: A simpler solution would be to add/remove a single class on a parent element. From there you can use CSS to add styling to the element which has the class and all it's children without having to change properties on a lot of DOM elements in one go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either use `find()`

```
$(this).find('*').attr('style','');
```

or the context selector

```
$('*', this).attr('style','');
```

to do the same thing as `$('#element *')` with `this`

If the element represented by `this` should be part of the collection, you can add it back

```
$(this).find('*').addBack().attr('style','');
```

---

I tend to agree with  Rory McCrossan in the comments, using a parent element and external styles would be preferable to changing the style attribute on multiple elements

```
.element.styled * { /* styles for all children */ }
```

then just

```
$('.element').removeClass('styled')
```

to remove the styles on the children

Comment: Wow... `addBack()` that's new to me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - it used to be called `andSelf` but changed name in jQ 1.8. Both `addBack` and `end` use the internal stack that jQuery keeps to add the previous element, or go back one step, and makes it a lot easier to create more complicated chains

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery's [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$(this).children().attr('style','');
```

However, this only goes down one level, so you could also use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find('*').attr('style','');
```

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/zofhwca6/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the children and then use `removeAttr`

```
$(this).children().removeAttr('style');
```

OR

```
$(this).find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery find methode will work:

```
$(this).find(selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(this).find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

Or even the contextual:

```
$('*', this).removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).children()`  can be used to select it's children
    further you can be specific like `$(this).children('.classname')`

Simillarly `$(this).parent()` can be used to select it's parent